# Creating a diamond outline

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon, sketch-app

I'm able to create a flat diamond will fills, but I'm having some difficulty getting just the outlines. I've tried using borders with inside position, but I end up with thicker strokes in certain areas. When I put them to center, I get these weird pointy corners. [image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want one outline just around the outside edge of the diamond, or outlines around each facet?

Comment: Good catch! I'm trying to outline around each facet.

Comment: Are you using Illustrator or Sketch? (you tagged both)

Comment: You're most certainly right. Sadly, I wouldn't have known that it was an anchor problem due to my ignorance on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) Make sure the triangles you created for the facets are fully closed paths (I re-created your diamond in about 60 seconds using the Polygon tool, creating 3-sided polygons and duplicating them). Meaning, make sure each facet is its own shape:

[image]

2) Then, when you add a stroke to each one (I used red to make it stand out more), make sure the "Corner" setting under "Stroke" is using the "Round Join" setting:

[image]